# OSMDroid Showing more than one maps and infinite scroll

Tags: android, openstreetmap, osmdroid

I have a simple Android application. I'm trying to display a simple Map (like we have in Google Maps). Following the [OSMDroid](https://github.com/osmdroid/osmdroid/wiki/How-to-use-the-osmdroid-library) website, i setup the app as instructed there.

I have the Manifest file as shown below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="sample.osmdroid.com.osmdroidsample">
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

I have my `MainActivity.java` as shown below:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    ArrayList<OverlayItem> anotherOverlayItemArray;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        Configuration.getInstance().setUserAgentValue(BuildConfig.APPLICATION_ID);

        //important! set your user agent to prevent getting banned from the osm servers
        Configuration.getInstance().load(getApplicationContext(), PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getApplicationContext()));
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        MapView map = (MapView) findViewById(R.id.map);
        map.setTileSource(TileSourceFactory.DEFAULT_TILE_SOURCE);

        map.setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
        map.setMultiTouchControls(true);


        IMapController mapController = map.getController();
        mapController.setZoom(2);

        map.setMaxZoomLevel(3);
        map.setMinZoomLevel(2);

    }

    @Override
    protected void onRestart() {
        super.onRestart();
        //this will refresh the osmdroid configuration on resuming.
        //if you make changes to the configuration, use
        //SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
        //Configuration.getInstance().save(this, prefs);
        Configuration.getInstance().load(this, PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this));
    }
}
```

The corresponding layout file `activity_main.xml` is as shown below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/activity_main"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="sample.osmdroid.com.osmdroidsample.MainActivity">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/myTxt"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Hello World!" />
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_below="@id/myTxt"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent">
        <org.osmdroid.views.MapView android:id="@+id/map"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
    </LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

The default output is as shown below:

[image]

**Problem:**
When i scroll the Map up/down or sideways, the out put turns something like this:

[image]

As you see in the above image there is not a single map in the screen. There are infinite number of them as you scroll, the map keeps coming on and on (Scrolling both horizontally and vertically).

My requirement is to have just one instance of the map like we have in Google Map API. So how can i achieve the same using OSMDroid?

```
P.S. I cannot use Google Maps API as the same is not supported in China.
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am currently struggling with the same issue. I found the following solution which avoids the "duplication" (from [OSMDROID displays multiple maps with polylines in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52212951/osmdroid-displays-multiple-maps-with-polylines-in-android))

```
MapView map = (MapView) findViewById(R.id.map);
map.setScrollableAreaLimitDouble(new BoundingBox(85, 180, -85, -180));
map.setMaxZoomLevel(20.0);
map.setMinZoomLevel(4.0);
map.setHorizontalMapRepetitionEnabled(false);
map.setVerticalMapRepetitionEnabled(false);
map.setScrollableAreaLimitLatitude(MapView.getTileSystem().getMaxLatitude(), 
MapView.getTileSystem().getMinLatitude(), 0);
```

Is not completely what I was looking for, but it could solve your problem. It uses the bounding box as mentioned by scai. I will look further to see whether there is an alternative

Answer (score 1):

For me the below code worked:

```
map.isHorizontalMapRepetitionEnabled = false
map.isVerticalMapRepetitionEnabled = false
```

So, in addition to your code, just add these two parameters before setting zoom value

Answer (score 0):

First, this is still just a single map since our world is round.

Second, you can call `setScrollableAreaLimit()` on your `MapView` object to limit the view to a specific `BoundingBox`.

Comment: Thanks for the Answer. But need more details. What is the area occupied by a single map(so that i can set the scroll-able area)? And world is round/spherical, but our representation is on a flat screen, so i need only one single instance of the map.

Comment: I haven't tried it but my guess is to specify a bounding box with lat from `>-90` to `<90` and lon from `>-180` to `<180`.