# OSMDROID displays multiple maps with polylines in Android

Tags: android, maps, osmdroid

*I see multiple maps with polyline when I start my android application. How can I show only one map?*

[image]

`MainActivity`:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    MapView map;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        Context ctx = getApplicationContext();
        Configuration.getInstance().load(ctx,    PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(ctx));
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);



       map = findViewById(R.id.mapViewMain);
       map.setTileSource(TileSourceFactory.DEFAULT_TILE_SOURCE);
       map.setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
       map.setMultiTouchControls(true);

    }

    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();       
        map.onPause();  
    }

    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        map.onPause();
    }


}
```

Layout `activity_main`:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <org.osmdroid.views.MapView
        android:id="@+id/mapViewMain"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />
</LinearLayout>
```

I want to see only one map on my device.

Comment: I do not understand what is actually the problem you are observing. Can you provide a screen shot please?

Comment: https://cloud.githubusercontent.com/assets/12249700/9302821/79b4435a-44d1-11e5-9b05-a213dbfea972.png

Answer (score 1):

I solved that with this:

```
MapView map = (MapView) findViewById(R.id.map);
map.setScrollableAreaLimitDouble(new BoundingBox(85, 180, -85, -180));
map.setMaxZoomLevel(20.0);
map.setMinZoomLevel(4.0);
map.setHorizontalMapRepetitionEnabled(false);
map.setVerticalMapRepetitionEnabled(false);
map.setScrollableAreaLimitLatitude(MapView.getTileSystem().getMaxLatitude(), MapView.getTileSystem().getMinLatitude(), 0);
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code is correct and you actually see only one map - meaning only on map component. The map is zoomed out too much and is smaller then the view. The osmdroid library solves this problem by repeating the map in the viewport. I don't think there is a way to turn this feature off.

You can solve the problem by setting some reasonable zoom level.

```
map.setZoomLevel(12)
```

Comment: @dEod I am sorry but I don't understand you question.

Comment: I  resolved 
        map.setScrollableAreaLimitDouble(new BoundingBox(85, 180, -85, -180));

Answer (score 0):

```
MapView map;
map.setHorizontalMapRepetitionEnabled(true);
map.setVerticalMapRepetitionEnabled(false);
map.setScrollableAreaLimitLatitude(MapView.getTileSystem().getMaxLatitude(), MapView.getTileSystem().getMinLatitude(), 0);
```

Answer (score 0):

This will set limits of scrollable area (on only one map):

```
map.setScrollableAreaLimitLatitude(
    MapView.getTileSystem().maxLatitude,
    MapView.getTileSystem().minLatitude,
    0
)
map.setScrollableAreaLimitLongitude(
    MapView.getTileSystem().minLongitude,
    MapVie.getTileSystem().maxLongitude,
    0
)
```